# Is the belief of distortion of quran kufr? How scholars interpret narrations hinting about such? What should a common Muslim do questioning his faith?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation, shia-sunni, belief

This issue got my little attention when I first watched a video sent by my shia friend of a scholar named Hassan Allahyari who holds the view that the quran that we have in our hands is distorted and original quran will be brought by the hidden imam i.e. imam mahdi. I already knew that this subject is used as a weapon against each other by sunnis and shias. Sunnis start first by accusing them of belief of tahreef doing takiyya and shias in reply don't remain silent and bring narrations from the sunni books hinting as though it's a distortion. The web is full of this fighting stuff by both sunni shia sites discrediting each other.

My question is now is there is no denying that these kind of narrations do exist, in both sunni and shias books even in bukhari and muslim and other sunan books as well. Here in Pakistan sunni scholars too admit this ,though some reject it completely despite of their authenticity and others make taaweel. Majority shias also disown this belief saying this is a propaganda and false allegation against shia as shias have always been a subject of hatred.

Now here in subcontinent a scholar named Hassan Allahyari gained popularity and started disseminating this doctrine of distortion openly and people have started believing in it. My question is what should a common Muslim react towards these and view or doctrine it should hold especially when this era of chaos and secterianism where these kind of heated controversies makes him question his faith? And why are sunni so dishonest by maligning and falsely accusing the opposing party of tahreef when their own books are full of this stuff?

Comment: As is written you leave us guessing what might be meant? Please explicitly name what distortion claims are there!

Comment: @Medi1Saif like portion of quran was lost. Or like verses of rajm and suckling. Or verse which was revealed differently like 'wa ma khalaqtaz zakara wa ma untha. Mawwidatain etc and its keep on going

Comment: Just because somebody quotes something doesn't necessarily mean that he regard it as authentic because at the end narrators are human and human make mistakes. The fact that they nevertheless quote these statements only show what is known as scientific honesty and equity, its presenting an information as one has learnt it, like saying it might be strange but we were informed via ... that X said such and such. Note that some of these reports are rather self explanatory in this reagrds.

Comment: The topics you have addressed have answers and are mainly no more discussed because the qur'anic text that 'Uthman has chosen as a standard mushaf was accepted by the ummah if 'Ali wanted to change it he would have had the chance for that but he didn't this is a nonverbal agreement. Some of these topics are related to earlier versions of the qur'an before the revelation ended -so that some verses were abrogated/removed- and some of them are related to the topic of ahruf and qira'at and what lead to the compilation of a mushaf. The issue here is that shi'a mainly reject the idea of abrogation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, believing that Quran was distorted is qufr (according to the sunni scholarship), because there are direct ayats in the Quran that are saying that Quran will be saved by Allah himself, so not believing these verses means not believing in Quran which is considered as qufr (once again, by sunnis, I don't know what about shias). Quick search in Google will answer to your doubts about it, so I won't copy every argument, just reference the ayats that are saying that Quran is protected:

[Quran 15:9] Translation: "Absolutely, we have revealed the reminder, and, absolutely, we will preserve it".

[Quran 56:77-80] Translation: "This is an honorable Quran. In a protected book. None can grasp it except the sincere. A revelation from the Lord of the universe".

[Quran 85:21-22] Translation: "Indeed, it is a glorious Quran. In a preserved master tablet".

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please mark your quotes as such to clearly distinguish them from your own words.